# Disable all Sundays in JSDatePicker Calendar

Tags: javascript

I am using the **jsDatePick.min.1.3.js** through my php code In that, I want to disable all Sunday in the datepicker, here is my JavaScript code snippet

```
function f () {
    new JSDatePick({
        useMode: 2,
        target: "dateval",
        dateFormat: "%Y/%m/%d"
    });
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Why is this tagged as php but you only include and talk about js? Can you clarify or include more details in the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The library does not specify the exact way to achieve the desired, but still you can use the following as an workaround :

```
var picker=new JsDatePick({
    useMode: 2,
    target: "picker"
});


picker.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
    var selectedDate = picker1.getSelectedDay();

    var d = new Date(selectedDate.year,selectedDate.month,selectedDate.day);
  //Check if sunday , if it is unset the selection and give a warning
  if(d.getDay() === 0){
    alert("Sundays are disabled");
    picker1.unsetSelection();
  }

});
```

This will ensure that no sundays are selected.